# Zend_Db_Table_Abstract not returning as an array?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have a class:

```
class Branches extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    protected $_name = 'branches';
    protected $_rowClass = 'branch';

    public function getBranches()
    {
        return $this->fetchAll();
    }

}
```

The problem is, getBranches returns an object of type: "Zend_Db_Table_Abstract". I was hoping to get an array of all the individual items, as would happen if I normally did a fetchAll. How can I get this to return an array of all the items?

Answer (score 3):

Use this

```
$rows = $this->fetchAll();
return $rows->toArray();
```